# SOQL Subquery - Standard Parent, Custom Child

Tags: apex, soql, query, relationships

Can someone help me understand why Im unable to execute the following query? Is it something obvious? Custom_Object__c has a lookup relationship to Contact.

```
select Id, (select Name from Custom_Object__r) 
from Contact
```

Im getting the following error when I run this query...

```
INVALID_TYPE: 
select Id, (select Name from Custom_Object__r)
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
Didn't understand relationship 'Custom_Object__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Comment: __r is for going 'up', while you're trying to go 'down' the relationship.

Comment: Exactly, that's a good way of putting it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the relationship name if Custom_Object__c were the parent.  In this case, that object is the child, so the relationship name is different.  If you go to the Custom_Object__c object, and look at the Contact lookup field, you need to find what the 'Child Relationship Name' is.  It's in the Lookup Options Section.

This is what you want to use in your query.  So you would replace `Custom_Object__r` with whatever that relationship name is.

[image]

Look at this link for some more clarification on using relationships in SOQL.  It s agreat resource.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: Perfect - my subqueries have now found a new lease of life now you've pointed out how the relationship name works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get the correct name for this.

Open up Eclipse -> Open up the Schema Browser in Eclipse -> Expand Contact -> Expand Child Relationships -> Expand your custom object -> Expand Fields -> Check 'Name'

This will build a query in your query results, and give you the correct relationship name.

Comment: @dphil : I used your tip and found it to be working(somewhat).I am working on a customer object and could see in schema browser there are many child relationship names for this object. However when i am using anything apart from openActivities and ActivityHistories..eg:NotesAndAttachments..It shows an error  "not a valid child relationship name for entity Job Application "..

Answer (score -2):

```
select Id, (select Name from Custom_Objects__r) 
from Contact
```

we need to give custom object plural label__r

Comment: This doesn't add a lot of information by itself, it'd be improved by adding where that name comes from!